# Url="undefined" when i click to addtodo

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I  have a household app that is relative to the user but when i click the button to go to the `addtodo` page, it loses the url of the house relative to the user which then leads to the `todolist` being stored as `undefined` on Firebase instead of the house the user choose. Any idea why this is ? I've tried passing the url as follows.

**Todolist.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from "@ionic/angular";
import { House, HouseService } from '../Services/house.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TodoserviceService } from '../Services/todoservice.service';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Todolist } from '../modal/Todolist';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from '../Services/user.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-todolist',
  templateUrl: './todolist.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todolist.page.scss'],
})
export class TodolistPage implements OnInit {
  minDate = new Date().toISOString();

  house;
  currentHouse:House;
  currentHouseId: string;
  DB;
  todoArray = [];

  todo = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    last_Date: new Date().toISOString(),

  }
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router,
    private houseService: HouseService,
    private userService: UserService,private navCtrl: NavController) { 
      //get ID of house from URL
      let id1 = this.router.url.split('id=');
      let id2 = id1[1].toString();
      let id3 = id2.split('/');
      let id = id3[0].toString();


      this.houseService.getHouse(id);
    if (id) {
      this.houseService.getHouse(id).subscribe(house => {
        this.currentHouse = house;
        this.house = id;
      });}
      //initialise DB             
  this.DB = this.afs.collection('house').doc(id).collection('todolist');

  this.DB.snapshotChanges().subscribe(colSnap => {
    this.todoArray = [];
    colSnap.forEach(snap => {
      let todo: any = snap.payload.doc.data();
      todo.id = snap.payload.doc.id;
      todo.last_Date = new Date(todo.last_Date).toDateString();
      this.todoArray.push(todo);
    });
  });

  }//end constructor

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  gotoAddToDo(house:string){
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['/add-todo',{id:house}]);
  }
}
```

**add-todo.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { House, HouseService } from '../Services/house.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TodoserviceService } from '../Services/todoservice.service';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Todolist } from '../modal/Todolist';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from '../Services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-todo',
  templateUrl: './add-todo.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-todo.page.scss'],
})



export class AddTodoPage implements OnInit {last_Date = new Date().toISOString();

  currentHouse;
  house;
  currentHouseId;
  DB;
  todoArray = [];

  todo = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    last_Date: new Date().toISOString(),

  }

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private router: Router,
              private houseService: HouseService,
              private userService: UserService) { 

                let id1 = this.router.url.split('id=');
                let id2 = id1[1].toString();
                let id3 = id2.split('/');
                let id = id3[0].toString();


                this.houseService.getHouse(id);
              if (id) {
                this.houseService.getHouse(id).subscribe(house => {
                  this.currentHouse = house;
                  this.house = id;
                });}

  //initialise DB             
  this.DB = this.afs.collection('house').doc(id).collection('todolist');

  this.DB.snapshotChanges().subscribe(colSnap => {
    this.todoArray = [];
    colSnap.forEach(snap => {
      let todo: any = snap.payload.doc.data();
      todo.id = snap.payload.doc.id;
      todo.last_Date = new Date(todo.last_Date).toDateString();
      this.todoArray.push(todo);
    });
  });

  }//end constructor

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  addtodo(){
    this.DB.add(this.todo);
    this.resetTodo();
    console.log("todoadded")
  }

  //fucntion to reset values of bill object
  resetTodo(){
    this.todo = {
      title: '',
      description: '',
      last_Date: new Date().toISOString(),
    }
  }


}
```

[Todo page with url relevant to that specific house](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyYbe.png)

[addtopage with url undeifned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsbLw.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are some probable causes for the issue that you are facing. I will try to provide the examples of what might be affecting you and the ways that you can take to fix it.

1. For your `{id:house}`, you might need to send it as a provider and then, load it in the `ngOnInit()` of the destination page. This way, your code would be something like this:

   ```
   @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class MyNavService {
      myParam: any; // of course replace any with a nice interface of your own
   }
   ```

   then in your calling page you do

   ```
   this.myNavService.myParam = {id:house};
   await this.navCtrl.goForward('/add-todo');
   ```

   and in the page where you need the param

   ```
   ngOnInit() {
      this.myObject = this.myNavService.myParam;
   }
   ```

   More information about this solution can be found [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-pass-data-between-pages/139601).
2. Another option, would be to send the parameter somewhat like you are doing, but with some differences. These differences can be seen in the below code:

   ```
   // Send Parameter in ToDoList
   import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
   import { NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
   //...
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }
   //...
     let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
     queryParams: {
         house: JSON.stringify(id),
         refresh: refresh
     }
   };
   this.navCtrl.navigateForward(['page-slug'], true, navigationExtras);

   // Receive Parameter add-todo
   import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
   //...
   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
   //...
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
     this.refresh = params["refresh"];
     this.currency = JSON.parse(params["house"]);
   });
   ```

   This code should help you send the parameters and receive them correctly, withou having the undefined send and then, generating the wrong URL. You can get more information about this other solution [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-pass-data-from-1-page-to-another-using-navigation-in-ionic-4/151060/2).

**These code samples are untested**, however, I believe they should help you as starting point for you to fix the issue within your application.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Hi @Keaner please, consider upvoting or accepting this answer, in case it helped you in anyway, to solve your problem.